# mocking a conditional window.open function call with jest

Tags: javascript, typescript, testing, mocking, jestjs

I am trying to write a test to make sure that, when and when i pass a valid URL arg to a function it runs `windows.open(args)` to open it. then to make sure that i focus on it.

**Test link validity:**

```
export function isValidURL(url: string): boolean {
  try {
    new URL(url)
    return true
  } catch (e) {
    console.warn(`Invalid URL: ${url}`)
    return false
  }
}
```

**Open link:**

```
export function openURL(url: string): void {
  if (isValidURL(url)) {
    const exTab = window.open(url, "_blank")
    if (exTab) exTab.focus()
  }
}
```

I thinked that i should mock some function or maybe to fake it's code, then wait for it's number of call or something like that. but i'm new with jest and testing and i feel so confused of how that can be done.

**My issay:**

```
describe("Test tools.openURL()", () => {
  test("it should open link if valid.", () => {
    const { open } = window
    delete window.open
    window.open = jest.fn()
    openURL("htts//url2.de9v")
    expect(window.open).not.toHaveBeenCalled()
    openURL("https://www.url1.dev")
    expect(window.open).toHaveBeenCalled()
    window.open = open
    // test focus here
  })
})
```

With this code i have succeeded to test the `open`, now i just need to test `focus`.

Comment: `window.open('htts//url2.de9v')` doesn't error

Comment: @r3wt I edited my essay based on another idea (_a workaround_), now i successed testing `open`.  I still need to test `focus` to have 100% coverage.
please take a look..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'open'` is readonly property.
Instead of `jest.spyOn(window, "open")` Try:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, 'open', { value: <your mock> });
```

in place of `<your mock>` locate mock object or object that should be returned.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it! please can you give me more hints?

Comment: @MalekBoubakri I've updated the answer. Instead of <your mock> place the object (or mock), that window.open should return

Comment: I edited my essay based on another idea (_a workaround_), now i successed testing `open`.  I still need to test `focus` to have 100% coverage.
please take a look..